# BIRT reporting - use the same parameter multiply times in a sql query

Tags: eclipse, birt

I have this where clause:

```
WHERE p.ROLE = 'doctor'
AND((p6.PA_Name='Event_Day_From' AND p6.PA_Value>= SUBSTRING('01.01.2012', 1, 2))
AND (p7.PA_Name='Event_Month_From' AND p7.PA_Value>=SUBSTRING('01.01.2012', 4, 2))
AND (p8.PA_Name='Event_Year_From' AND P8.PA_Value>=SUBSTRING('01.01.2012', 7, 4)))
AND ((p9.PA_Name='Event_Day_To' AND P9.PA_Value<=SUBSTRING('30.12.2012', 1, 2))
AND (p10.PA_Name='Event_Month_To' AND P10.PA_Value<=SUBSTRING('30.12.2012', 4, 2))
AND (p11.PA_Name='Event_Year_To' AND P11.PA_Value<=SUBSTRING('30.12.2012', 7, 4)))
```

after the above I have an `union all` and at the end I have another `WHERE` clause exacly the same as the above.

In BIRT a parameter can be passed and you have to insert `?` in the SQL query where you need it to be passed. As you can see I have a **start** date and an **end** date wich will be passed trough an **user input**. Now my problem is that I have no idea how to pass the `SDate` parameter to all the `start dates` and the `EndDate` parameter to all the `end dates`

Is there a solution for my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by creating table with a single row from the parameters, and attaching it to the report query like so:

```
,(select ? SDate, ? EDate) params
WHERE p.ROLE = 'doctor'
AND((p6.PA_Name='Event_Day_From' AND p6.PA_Value>= SUBSTRING(params.SDate, 1, 2))
AND (p7.PA_Name='Event_Month_From' AND p7.PA_Value>=SUBSTRING(params.SDate, 4, 2))
AND (p8.PA_Name='Event_Year_From' AND P8.PA_Value>=SUBSTRING(params.SDate, 7, 4)))
AND ((p9.PA_Name='Event_Day_To' AND P9.PA_Value<=SUBSTRING(params.EDate, 1, 2))
AND (p10.PA_Name='Event_Month_To' AND P10.PA_Value<=SUBSTRING(params.EDate, 4, 2))
AND (p11.PA_Name='Event_Year_To' AND P11.PA_Value<=SUBSTRING(params.EDate, 7, 4)))
```

Hope this helps.

**I use this method on a PostgreSQL database currently.

Comment: what are the names of your parameters here ? and how does BIRT get them ?

Answer (score 1):

**[EDIT]** BIRT uses plain JDBC not it's not supporting "named parameters", so you can't write:

```
... p6.PA_Value>= SUBSTRING(:start, 1, 2) ...
```

This will give an error.

Other options are to build the query using Property Binding or JavaScript and replace parts of it before it is executed. [See this example report](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/examples/reports/birt2.1/querymod/index.php)

Some databases also support the `WITH` syntax to assign an alias to a `?` parameter. [This blog post](http://enterprisesmartapps.wordpress.com/2011/01/10/re-using-parameters-in-birt-data-set/) explains how to use this.

Comment: Which database? There is a workaround when you use Oracle: http://enterprisesmartapps.wordpress.com/2011/01/10/re-using-parameters-in-birt-data-set/

Comment: I am using microsoft sql server

Comment: Okay, I've completely overworked my answer. Try the dynamic query modification. It's not perfect but works in your case since you only need strings.

Comment: is there a way to pass the parameters to a procedure?

Comment: BIRT supports calling stored procedures: http://wiki.eclipse.org/StoredProcedure_(BIRT)